# Confused with Rules in Scrapy in python spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have one doubt in scrapy spider. Suppose i ahve this code

```
 name = 'myspider'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/foo/']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'-\w+.html$'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

I want to know that will the spider first go to the start url and parse the page and then use rules for extracting  links

or spider don't parse the first page but will start with rules

I have seen that if my rules don't match then i don't get any results but at least don't it should have parsed the starting page

Comment: What does the output look like when your rules don't match?

Comment: the command lines comes up with some text and says crawled 0 pages. i am extending from crawlspider. i was thinking that how will the spider know that i ahve to use `parse_item` function because that was the only function i have and that was mentioned only in rules. is that the base

Answer (score 2):

I was coding a sample tutorial by Michael Herman,  https://github.com/mjhea0/Scrapy-Samples, which began with the BaseSpider example and progressed to the CrawlSpider example. No big deal with the first  example, but the second example was not scraping the first page -- only the second page -- and I had no clue as to what I was doing wrong. However, when I ran the code from github, I realized that his code was not scraping the first page as well! I suppose it has something to do with the intent of CrawlSpider vs BaseSpider and after doing a little research, I came up with this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist.items import CraigslistItem
from scrapy.http     import Request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "CraigslistSpider"
allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
start_urls = ["http://annapolis.craigslist.org/sof/"]

rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html", ),
    restrict_xpaths=('//p[@id="nextpage"]',)),
    callback="parse_items", follow= True),
)

#
# Need to scrape first page...so we hack-it by creating request and
# sending the request to the parse_items callback
#
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    print ('**********************')
    request = Request("http://annapolis.craigslist.org/sof/", callback=self.parse_items)
    return request

def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//p")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistItem()
        item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

In my case, I was using CrawlSpider, which required me to implement 'parse_start_url' to create a request object using the same url found in start_urls, i.e., the first page. Afterwards, scraping started on the first page. BTW, I'm 3 days old with scrapy and python!

Comment: actually, i don't think your answer solved the question, the question is asking the order start_urls and rules, which one would be used to start crawling.